# What does adding to a GLuint attribute index do?

Tags: opengl, mobile, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm currently reading some code (specifically example code for the *Oculus Mobile* SDK which just renders some coloured cubes floating around) where he retrieves a vertex shader attribute with `glGetAttribLocation` (in the shader it's a `mat4`, it's the transform matrix), then a little further down he does some stuff where he adds to that shader attribute index.

```c
VertexTransformAttribute = glGetAttribLocation( Program.Program, "VertexTransform" );

//some stuff happens in between

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
{
    GL( glEnableVertexAttribArray( VertexTransformAttribute + i ) );
    GL( glVertexAttribPointer( VertexTransformAttribute + i, 4, GL_FLOAT,
                            false, 4 * 4 * sizeof( float ), (void *)( i * 4 * sizeof( float ) ) ) );
    GL( glVertexAttribDivisor( VertexTransformAttribute + i, 1 ) );
}
```

To some extent, I understand that he's doing something with the transform matrix for all cubes, but I'm not sure what adding to the index does.

Any help explaining this part would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every vertex attribute delivers 4 values to OpenGL, even if you don't use all 4 of them. But in GLSL, you can use [matrices and arrays of types for the type of a vertex shader input variable](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Multiple_attributes). Since these take more than 4 values, you need more than 1 attribute to deliver the data, despite having only declared one actual variable.

So the attribute location for the input variable's name is the first attribute index. And OpenGL automatically assigns the next X attribute indices, consecutively, to fulfill the request for your variable. In the case of a `mat4`, that is a 4x4 matrix. So OpenGL needs to assign it 4 attributes total, with each attribute representing a single column of the matrix. These are assigned in order, starting from the attribute index associated with the variable name and ending 3 attribute indices later.

Comment: To expand, what specifically is happening in this example is that the example writer is pushing the model transform (usually represented as a mat4) for each rendered object into a buffer, so that subsequently they can all be rendered with a single call to an instanced call.  See http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing for more details, including a section where the author does something similar, but without using a loop.